# Decode and aggregate a BitMask in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, aggregate

I have a table that contains a bitmask field that stores permissions, where each bit denotes whether a particular permission is granted or not.  Here's a simplified example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id smallint identity, BitMask tinyint);
INSERT INTO @T (BitMask) VALUES
  (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);


SELECT
  t.id, t.BitMask, bm.BitNum, bm.Permission
FROM @T t
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (t.id, 0, 'Can X'),
    (t.id, 1, 'Can Y'),
    (t.id, 2, 'Can Z')
  ) bm(id, BitNum, Permission)
  WHERE t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum) <> 0
) bm
```

This returns the following info:

```
id     BitMask BitNum      Permission
------ ------- ----------- ----------
1      0       NULL        NULL
2      1       0           Can X
3      2       1           Can Y
4      3       0           Can X
4      3       1           Can Y
5      4       2           Can Z
6      5       0           Can X
6      5       2           Can Z
7      6       1           Can Y
7      6       2           Can Z
8      7       0           Can X
8      7       1           Can Y
8      7       2           Can Z
9      8       NULL        NULL
10     9       0           Can X

(15 row(s) affected)
```

So far so good.  The trouble comes when I try to do an aggregate by id, so that I have all the permissions in one field.  I've tried adding the following `APPLY` clause to do a standard XML list-string-agg, but I get an error `Invalid object name 'bm'.`:

```
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT 
   ParamList = STUFF(
     (
       SELECT  '; ' + a.Permission
       FROM bm a WHERE a.id = b.id
       ORDER BY a.BitNum
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
     ), 1, 2, ''
   )
  FROM bm b
  GROUP BY b.id
) q
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we need to make a few minor adjustments to the original code:

1. It does not make sense to have a permission value of `0` since `0` means "no permissions".
2. The "BitNum" is not the direct value that you use in the `POWER` function. If you need a "bit" value of `1`, that comes from raising 2 to the power of `0`. So you need to subtract `1` from the "BitNum" for use in the `POWER` function.

With those two changes in mind, the following changes to the original query give you the correct initial result set:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (id SMALLINT IDENTITY(1, 1), BitMask TINYINT);
INSERT INTO @T (BitMask) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

SELECT  t.id, t.BitMask, bm.BitNum, bm.Permission
FROM    @T t
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'Can Y'),
    (2, 'Can Z')
  ) bm(BitNum, Permission)
  WHERE t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1) <> 0
) bm
```

And that query can be further reduced / simplified to be a simple `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```sql
SELECT  t.id, t.BitMask, bm.BitNum, bm.Permission
FROM    @T t
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    (1, 'Can Y'),
    (2, 'Can Z')
          ) bm(BitNum, Permission)
  ON t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1) <> 0
```

Results (12 rows):

```
id  BitMask BitNum  Permission
1   0       NULL    NULL
2   1       1       Can Y
3   2       2       Can Z
4   3       1       Can Y
4   3       2       Can Z
5   4       NULL    NULL
6   5       1       Can Y
7   6       2       Can Z
8   7       1       Can Y
8   7       2       Can Z
9   8       NULL    NULL
10  9       1       Can Y
```

Next, now that we have the proper base query, you cannot simply add an `APPLY` since your original query had each permission as a separate row but now you want them grouped into a single row per "BitMask". Hence you need to restructure the request to be the following (or something similar):

```sql
SELECT   t.id, t.BitMask, PermissionList = 
(
  SELECT PermissionList = STUFF(
     (
       SELECT  '; ' + bm.Permission
       FROM   (VALUES
                    (1, 'Can Y'),
                    (2, 'Can Z')
              ) bm(BitNum, Permission)
        WHERE  t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1) <> 0
        ORDER BY bm.BitNum
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
   )
)
FROM @T t
GROUP BY t.id, t.BitMask;
```

Results (10 rows):

```
id  BitMask     PermissionList
1   0           NULL
2   1           Can Y
3   2           Can Z
4   3           Can Y; Can Z
5   4           NULL
6   5           Can Y
7   6           Can Z
8   7           Can Y; Can Z
9   8           NULL
10  9           Can Y
```

You also have the option of using SQLCLR to create a User-Defined Aggregate (UDA) that can do this type of `String.Join()` operation. And an Aggregate function such as this already exists in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=ds_103075) library (which I am the author of, but this function is available in the Free version), though it is hard-coded to use a comma (and no spaces) as the delimiter, and returns an empty string instead of NULL if there are no matches. But, it does make for a much more readable query:

```sql
SELECT  t.id, t.BitMask, SQL#.Agg_Join(bm.Permission) AS [PermissionList]
FROM    @T t
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    (1, 'Can Y'),
    (2, 'Can Z')
          ) bm(BitNum, Permission)
  ON t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1) <> 0
GROUP BY t.id, t.BitMask;
```

This is not to say that using a SQLCLR UDA is necessarily the better choice, I am just pointing out that it is *a* choice, and depending on the specific requirements, might be better.

OR, starting in SQL Server 2017, there is a built-in aggregate function, [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql), that can handle this.

---

A slightly different way of testing the Bit value against the Bitmask is to compare the bit-wise AND operation of them to the Bit value itself instead of against `<> 0`:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (id SMALLINT IDENTITY(1, 1), BitMask TINYINT);
INSERT INTO @T (BitMask) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

 -- based on "improved" query
SELECT   t.id, t.BitMask, [PermissionList] = 
(
  SELECT [PermissionList] = STUFF(
     (
       SELECT  '; ' + bm.Permission
       FROM   (VALUES
                    (0, 'Default'),
                    (1, 'Can Y'),
                    (2, 'Can Z')
              ) bm(BitNum, Permission)
        WHERE  t.BitMask & POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1) = POWER(2, bm.BitNum - 1)
        ORDER BY bm.BitNum
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
   )
)
FROM @T t
GROUP BY t.id, t.BitMask;
```

This gets you a little closer to using `0` as a value, but then you have the problem of that value being implicitly in all records. The results of the above (notice that the `ON` condition was changed AND I added the `0` record back in):

```
id  BitMask     PermissionList
1   0           Default
2   1           Default; Can Y
3   2           Default; Can Z
4   3           Default; Can Y; Can Z
5   4           Default
6   5           Default; Can Y
7   6           Default; Can Z
8   7           Default; Can Y; Can Z
9   8           Default
10  9           Default; Can Y
```

Comment: Why do you say that a permissions value of 0 makes no sense?  Since this table stores a particular type of permissions, it's very valid in my use case.  Or think of it as options, with 0 getting the defaults and each bit turning on some extra bell/whistle, if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: @JoeNahmias I am saying that it doesn't make sense from a bit-masking perspective. The test to determine if a permission (i.e. any of the "bit" nums) is present in the mask is `<> 0`. Hence it will never come through as a selected option. Another way to look at this is that having 0 can not be distinguished from testing for a bit that is not in the mask: `SELECT 5 & 1 AS [HasBit], 5 & 2 AS [MissingBit], 0 & 0 [HasBitOrMissingBit?]`. Though I suppose maybe changing the ON condition might help to test the bitwise operation against itself instead of against `<> 0`.

Comment: I think you're trying to say that the bit numbers should start from 1, rather than 0, which is why you subtract one from the exponent in the call to POWER().  If so, I can accept that; but then you should have 1, 2, 3.  Oh, no CLR allowed in this DB, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @JoeNahmias I updated with a new section below the line to make it easier to find. I changed the `ON` condition to be a little more accurate, though it doesn't truly help since now the `0` value will _always_ be there as opposed to _never_ being there ;-). What I am saying is: **1)** `0` is not a meaningful option/bit value to use, and **2)** when doing the `POWER()` function, you need to subtract 1 from the Bit NUMBER (i.e. the position) for that option for the math to work correctly. Bit POSITIONS 1, 2, 3, and 4 correspond to bit VALUES 1, 2, 4, and 8. Hence, `POWER(2, POSITION-1) = VALUE`